# DataTable smart search issue without string order on 1 column

Tags: jquery, filter, datatable

I am facing an issue regarding DataTable search column.
Single-word searching is working absolutely fine. The issue, I am facing now I have a string with a comma separator. e.g.

> string = a,b,c,d

I am searching like this

> string = a
>   or 
>   string = a,b

It's working fine and giving me the records.

But when I am searching like this

> string = a,c

It's not showing the results.

```
table_column_string = a,b,c
checked = a,c
table.columns(':contains(Delivery Status)').search(checked).draw();
```

It's not filtering.
Working with if
checked = a,b

> Original Example
>
> Status Delivery Column value = No Sticker on Door,Signature not Valid,No Direction

```
table.columns(':contains(Delivery Status)').search('No Sticker on Door,No Direction').draw();
```

> It's not showing me the row.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Could you show an actual example of your code. The JS you've shown is syntactically broken.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Please check updated question. Hope it will give you the scenario.

Comment: Your update still contains invalid code

Comment: It's showing fine on my side. Don't know why it's broken on your side.

Comment: Your last edit fixed it - it was the missing quotes around the search string

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan great. Please help me out with this situation.

Comment: The solution is to use Regex for searching: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/46420/how-do-i-use-search-to-look-for-multiple-values

Comment: Also please read comment on this page https://datatables.net/reference/api/search()#

Comment: Hey @RoryMcCrossan. My issue is still there. Do you have anyother suggestion?

Comment: As I said previously, you need to use a regex. Simply change the `,` characters to `|` and enable regular expression searching. If you take the time to read the duplicate you can see a full example

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I did try regex and its showing nothing. column value in row is A,B,C and my searching value is A|C it should filter A,B,C row.
The example you giving is filtering multi rows tokyo in 1 row and london in another. Tokyo|london. But i need to search value in same row Tokyo,london,UAE with search string Tokyo|UAE